# Pass Range in Function, Sum Adjacent Cells, and Return Sum

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Excel table:

[image: Sample Image]

I want to pass the first column as a string, determine the address of the cells called 'LNA' and 'LCAMP', and sum the adjacent cells 'between' those two addresses. My failed code:

```
Function LNAtoLCAMP(ComponentList) As Single

Dim i As Integer
Dim LBoundAddress As Variant, UBoundAddress As Variant

For i = LBound(ComponentList) To UBound(ComponentList)
    If ComponentList(i, 1).Value = "LNA" Then
        LBoundAddress = ComponentList(i, 1).Address.Offset(0, 1)
    End If
    If ComponentList(i, 1).Value = "LCAMP" Then
        UBoundAddress = ComponentList(i, 1).Address.Offset(0, 1)
    End If
Next

LNAtoLCAMP = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(LBoundAddress, ":", UBoundAddress)

End Function
```

Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: What is the definition of 'ComponentList' and how is it populated? It looks like an array.

Comment: Wayne, yes, ComponentList is an array. It is the list in column B of the table in the picture I posted. It is passed in the function call in the cell like this: =LNAtoLCAMP(B16:B61)

Comment: Why not just store the values of the cells in two variables and have your function variable = var1 + var2?

Comment: There are many issues that need to be solved in your code. I can give you a possible solution but can you clear your requirement? You want a function entered in a cell? And also, you need to sum the numbers between **LNA** and **LCAMP**? Is that correct? Which are the highlighted numbers in your screen shot? I think that is quite hard to do since you did not specify a boundary for **LCAMP**. Up to where will I sum the values under it?

Comment: @L42, I call the function in a cell and the result (the sum) is displayed there. Yes, sum the numbers between LNA and LCAMP. In the example table shown, the function would sum the values 24 + 26 + 56, because they are 'between' 'LNA' and 'LCAMP'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function LNAtoLCAMP() As Single
   Dim LNA As Range, LCAMP As Range

   With Sheets("Sheet1")
       Set LNA = .Range("B:B").Find("LNA").Offset(0, 1)
       Set LCAMP = .Range("B:B").Find("LCAMP").Offset(0, 1)
       If Not LNA Is Nothing And Not LCAMP Is Nothing Then _
           LNAtoLCAMP = Evaluate("SUM(" & .Range(LNA, LCAMP).Address & ")")
   End With
End Function
```

**Edit2:** For your dynamic needs.

```
Function CONSUM(rng As Range, str1 As String, str2 As String, _
        Optional idx As Long = 1) As Variant
    Application.Volatile '<~~ autoupdate on cell change, remove otherwise
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = rng.Find(str1, rng(1), , xlWhole)
    Set r2 = rng.Find(str2, rng(1), , xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
    If Not r1 Is Nothing And Not r2 Is Nothing Then _
        CONSUM = Application.Sum(rng.Parent.Range(r1.Offset(0, idx), _
        r2.Offset(0, idx))) Else CONSUM = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

In the second function, you can select the range you search and also specify the string you want to search.
 It returns `#VALUE!` error if the strings you specify are not found. HTH.

For **Edit2** offset is dynamic as well (default at 1). Also this will sum the first instance of the 1st string up to the last instance of the second which was raised by chrisneilsen.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: L42, I'm afraid I can't use your suggestion because I need to pass the list as an array, since I have many such lists, not just the one in column B.

Comment: @Max I'm sorting that out and will add an edit soon. I'm just trying to test something :)

Comment: @Max I added the edit. The range and strings can now be passed to the function. This also works for ranges on other sheets. I just noticed your screen shot. The values you highlighted are actually in Column D. If that is the case, it should be `.Offset(0, 2)` or you can add another argument which will specify the offset.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your persistence. You guys amaze me. Good night and thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I've taken the column offset into account. I should have posted a cleaner screenshot.

Comment: Please be aware this will find and sum between the _first_ instance of the search strings in the list, which contradicts the OP's reply to a comment of mine

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yep. The first instance of the second string. But it can be easily adjusted by supplying the `SearchDirection` for the second string search if that is really the case.

Comment: @L42 Just saying, for the benifit of future readers (the OP doesn't seem to know _what_ he wants!)  btw, the `CVErr` constant should be `xlErrValue`

Answer (score 3):

According to your comment you are calling the function as

```
=LNAtoLCAMP(B16:B61)
```

This is *not* passing an array, it is passing a `range` (that's a good thing)

Your function, modified:

```
Function LNAtoLCAMP(ComponentList As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim Sum As Double

    Dim LBoundAddress As Long, UBoundAddress As Long

    dat = ComponentList.Value
    For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
        Select Case dat(i, 1)
            Case "LNA", "LCAMP"
                If LBoundAddress = 0 Then
                    LBoundAddress = i
                End If
                If i > UBoundAddress Then
                    UBoundAddress = i
                End If
        End Select
    Next

    For i = LBoundAddress To UBoundAddress
        Sum = Sum + dat(i, 2)
    Next
    LNAtoLCAMP = Sum
End Function
```

Call it with *both* columns in the range

```
=LNAtoLCAMP(B16:C61)
```

Note:

1. I have assumed you want to include hidden rows in the sum, and "Between" includes the rows LNA and LCAMP are on.  Both these assumptions are easily modified if required.
2. I have also assumed you want to sum from the *first* instance of *either* string to the *last* instance of *either* string.  Also easily modified if required.
3. You could also pass in the search strings to make it more flexable.
4. You should add error handling, eg if one of the search string is not in the list

Comment: chris, thanks for clarifying about the passed range. Your solution looks good, but it's not working for me. NOTE: I did initialize sum = 0, but otherwise I can't see any issues. Still stumped.

Comment: Can you clarify if my assumptions are correct.  And what result do you get with my function: an error or an incorrect sum?

Comment: chris, yes, those assumptions are correct. The function call still returns #VALUE! for me

Comment: FWIW, this code is tried and tested.  If the OP still gets an error then there is something else going on in his code (eg is it offset 1 as per the sample code, or offset 2 as per the screen shot?)

Comment: Chris, I'm sure it's on my end. I'll figure it out and report back.

Comment: Chris, as you suggested, my offset was incorrect. Works now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using an ApplicationFunction then you need quotes.

Also I believe it should be `.offset().address` (Needs to be flipped)

TESTED WORKING:

```
Function LNAtoLCAMP(ByVal ComponentList As Range) As Single
    Dim LBoundAddress As Range, UBoundAddress As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In ComponentList
        If cel.Value = "LNA" Then
            Set LBoundAddress = cel.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
        If cel.Value = "LCAMP" Then
            Set UBoundAddress = cel.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next cel
    LNAtoLCAMP = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(LBoundAddress, UBoundAddress))
End Function
```

Comment: @Christmas, thank you for the correction, but the overall function still does not work.

Comment: Christmas007, the .offset().address flip worked, but the "ByVal ComponentList As Range" produced a compile error: "Expected Array"

Comment: I'm going to make an edit to this in a little bit (I'm writing the code on mobile and it needs some work.

Comment: Again on mobile so can you see what I am trying to do (you'll need to make slight changes)

Comment: Christmas007, I tried it but no luck. Function returns #VALUE!

Comment: Christmas007, L42's code worked for me. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Max I finally got it working... Stupid mobile... Tested working